# In python, using datetime calculate result is error

Tags: python, datetime

Using python  calculate same time difference on May 4th and May 1st. but get different result

```
a = datetime(1986, 5, 4, 7, 13, 22).timestamp() - datetime(1986, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()
```

and

```
b = datetime(1986, 5, 1, 7, 13, 22).timestamp() - datetime(1986, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()
```

the results are different, one is `22402.0`, another is `26002.0`

Comment: Are you sure? https://ideone.com/mkw15D

Comment: My best guess: they are one hour different because your time zone implements daylight savings time, and one of these ranges crosses the DST changeover and the other doesn't. I can't replicate it, however.

Comment: By the way, you can directly subtract `datetime` instances, giving you a `timedelta` instance.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are in China, where in 1986 the daylight savings time started on May 4, so the differences will not be the same.

China was the only country to do so at this day, so this will not be reproductible in other countries.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/china?year=1986

Comment: your guess is right. Thanks, your answer is very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

In support of @alemangui's answer, you get `a==b` if you set the tzinfo property to UTC. The point is that you create naive datetime objects, of which Python assumes they belong in your *local* timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

a = (datetime(1986, 5, 4, 7, 13, 22, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() - 
     datetime(1986, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
b = (datetime(1986, 5, 1, 7, 13, 22, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() - 
     datetime(1986, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())

print(a, b, a==b)
# 26002.0 26002.0 True
```

vs.

```
from dateutil import tz

a = (datetime(1986, 5, 4, 7, 13, 22, tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Shanghai')).timestamp() - 
     datetime(1986, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Shanghai')).timestamp())
b = (datetime(1986, 5, 1, 7, 13, 22, tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Shanghai')).timestamp() - 
     datetime(1986, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Shanghai')).timestamp())

print(a, b, a==b)
# 22402.0 26002.0 False
```